# How to delete Selected item on python ttk treeview from the mysql database and the treeview?

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, ttk

Hi so I'm trying to delete selected items from the treeview and the database i worked on some code but it keeps failing

Here is the code

```
def delete():

    selected_item = tree.selection()[0]

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="root",
        database="loginsystem"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_select_Query = ("DELETE FROM data WHERE idData = '%s'")
    mycursor.execute(sql_select_Query, selected_item)
    mydb.commit()
    tree.delete(selected_item)
    print('delete')

def viewdata():
    global screen7
    global tree
    screen7 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen7.title("HOT or SUPER HOT(GUEST)")
    screen7.geometry("800x450+550+220")

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="root",
        database="loginsystem"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_select_Query = "select * from data"
    mycursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()

    height = 5
    width = 2

    tree = ttk.Treeview(screen7 ,style="mystyle.Treeview")

    selected_items = tree.selection()

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 11))  # Modify the font of the body
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13, 'bold'))  # Modify the font of the headings
    style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])  # Remove the borders

    tree["columns"] = ("one", "two")
    tree.column("one", width=200)
    tree.column("two", width=200)

    tree.heading("#0", text='ID', anchor='center')
    tree.column("#0", anchor="center")
    tree.heading("one", text="Car")
    tree.heading("two", text="Quantity")

    tree.tag_configure('odd', background='#E8E8E8')
    tree.tag_configure('even', background='#DFDFDF')

    cpt = 0  # Counter representing the ID of your code.
    for row in records:
        # I suppose the first column of your table is ID
        tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(cpt), values=(row[1], row[2]), tags =('ttk', 'simple'))
        cpt += 1  # increment the ID
    tree.place(x = 100, y = 130)

    Label(screen7,text = "DATA" , bg = "black", width = w , height = h, font = ("Calibri", 20) , fg = "white").pack()
    Button(screen7, text="Back", height=h, width="20", command=on_closemindta).place(x=500, y=380)
    Button(screen7, text="Add", height=h, width="20", command=adddata).place(x=150, y=380)
    Button(screen7, text="Delete", height=h, width="20", command=delete).place(x=325, y=380)
```

and everytime i run it it gives me an error of Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%s' i dont really know what that means , Is there something I'm Missing? 
Here is the full Error code printed when i click the delete button

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/Pylog/App.py", line 420, in delete
    mycursor.execute(sql_select_Query, selected_item)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%s'
```

Comment: It means that the `%s` in your query isn't a valid integer. You literally have that string in your query.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because you give a string to the query while an integer was expected  in your query replace

```
'%s' by %s
```